How to Load a file which is saved using BinaryFormatter
In our Control, we have used BinaryFormatter serialization to Save and Load. But in Net 9 BinaryFormatter is completely removed. Due to that, we are planned to write our Serialization logic using DataContractSerialization.
We have used many Classes in our Control and Serialized all of them. Our Structure is basically like this.
Serializable Class ---> Properties of Custom Class Types ---> Properties of Custom Class Types ---> Properties with basic DataTypes.
But we need to deserialize the old files which are saved using BinaryFormatter. Is there any way to read those files?

I don't know enough about this to answer, but I did find BinaryFormatter PayloadReader API #102014 and Make System.Formats.Nrbf public #103232.  There are a lot of issues under repo:dotnet/winforms binaryformatter as well.

You may want to ask at https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues and/or Announcement: BinaryFormatter is being removed in .NET 9 #98245 as well as here.

If migrating to some other serialization engine is too difficult (e.g. your classes do not expose everything by public properties, so an XML or JSON serialization would not work out of the box), then you can try my IFormatter-compatible binary serializer (NuGet). Please note though that the actual binary stream is not compatible with BinaryFormatter so a one time migration would be necessary.
